# File handling in C: can't fathom the output

Tags: c, file-handling

I compiled this (gcc compiler) :

```
#include< stdio.h>

 main() {

    unsigned char ch;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("trial","r");
    while((ch=getc(fp))!=EOF)
        printf("%c",ch);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

It gives the follwing:

```
Warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of the data type
```

On executing, an endless stream of characters is printed on terminal. 
(Assuming I created a file named "trial" before compiling the program and wrote some text in the file.)

Kindly explain the warning.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `EOF` value in C is an `int` while `ch` here is a `char`.  The `char` type is smaller than `int` and hence can represent less values than `int` can.  `EOF` is one of the values which `char` simply can't ever represent and hence `ch` will never be equal to `EOF`.

In this scenario `getc` actually returns an `int` so it can represent `EOF`.  But you are immediately shrinking it to a `char` and losing that extra information.

Here's a way to properly write this.

```
int cur;
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("trial","r");
while((cur = getc(fp))!=EOF) {
  unsigned char ch = cur;
  printf("%c",ch);
}
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: If I take normal char (unlike unsigned char) then it can represent values from -128 to +127 and EOF is numerically -1. Is it possible then for signed char to match EOF?

Comment: @Abhay, no.  The problem is more complicated than that.  EOF is an integer -1 which is represented differently than a char -1.  It is done on purpose so that you could not confuse a character value with an end of file indicator.

Answer (score 1):

Because EOF is -1 and your `ch` is unsigned char which means ch will never become -1.

Instead use `int ch;`

Comment: Strictly speaking, that's not true.  An unsigned char can never be negative, but if you tested an unsigned char of value 255 with a char of value -1, you'd find they're the same thing (though compiler would certainly give you a thorough warning).

Comment: If I take normal char (unlike unsigned char) then it can represent values from -128 to +127 and EOF is numerically -1. Is it possible then for signed char to match EOF?

Comment: @Abhay, EOF is in stdio.h as #define EOF -1 So it's straight forward to compare it with integer.

Answer (score 0):

`getc()` returns an `int`.  You're truncating (and changing the signedness) it to `unsigned char` with that assignment, so it will never match `EOF`.  Just change the type of `ch` to `int` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Can you please explain what is the EOF character in C and what is its integer value?

Answer (score 0):

`getc` returns an integer for good reason.  The EOF indicator is outside the range of a normal char, because otherwise you could confuse a legitimate character with the EOF indicator.  However, you're assigning the results to a character which confines the answer to fall within the limits of a `char` value.  In short, you're never going to know when the end of the file has been reached this way.  Make "ch" an `int` type or assign result from call to `getc` to an `unsigned char` type *after* you compare it with EOF.